# Matching specific types in Rust with Enums

Tags: rust

So in a particular expression, I want to do the following:
I have a class like given below:

```
pub type Variable = char;

#[derive(Clone,Debug,PartialEq,Eq)]
pub enum Atom {
    Base(Variable),
    Not(Variable)
}

pub type Clause = Vec<Atom>;

pub type Formula = Vec<Clause>;
```

Next this Class is included in my file like so:

```
pub mod cnf_formula;
use cnf_formula::*;

pub fn find_propogatable(f:& Formula) -> Option<(Variable,bool)> {
    for clause in f {
        if clause.len() == 1{
            if clause[0] == Atom::Base() {

            }
        }
    }
    
    return None;
}
```

Now what this find_propogatable function needs to do is to check the Formula passed in, if the formula only has one Atom, then you we return a value depending on whether the singleton clause is of type:

```
Atom::Base(*)
Atom::Not(*)
```

Where * can be any character. Now I am having a hard time trying to match Atom::Base(*) if I just provide it Atom::Base() it complains about missing parameters. How do I match it so it matches Atom::Base(*) where * can be any character?

Comment: `Atom::Base(_)`?

Comment: `if let Atom::Base(_) = clause[0]`. Have you read about [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) in the Rust book?